# How to get ID from guild.fetch in discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the Guild id when my bot joins the Discord server for the first time. I need the ID so the bot can automatically set up the roles.

I'm using the [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event, and inside the event, I'm using [`guild.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetch) to read the data of the collection. Now I only want the value of the `id`, how do I accomplish that?

Output of `guild.fetch()`:

```
Guild {
  members: GuildMemberManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection(3) [Map] {
      '36489644504160xxxx' => [GuildMember],
      '53517224246470xxxx' => [GuildMember],
      '53522344090743xxxx' => [GuildMember]
    },
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  channels: GuildChannelManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection(4) [Map] {
      '71558241555944xxxx' => [CategoryChannel],
      '71558241555944xxxx' => [CategoryChannel],
      '71558241555944xxxx' => [TextChannel],
      '71558241555944xxxx' => [VoiceChannel]
    },
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  roles: RoleManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection(5) [Map] {
      '71258641511471xxxx' => [Role],
      '75251159040894xxxx' => [Role],
      '75253768894955xxxx' => [Role],
      '75295113917353xxxx' => [Role],
      '75270698461845xxxx' => [Role]
    },
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  presences: PresenceManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection(3) [Map] {
      '36489644504160xxxx' => [Presence],
      '52517224246470xxxx' => [Presence],
      '52522344090743xxxx' => [Presence]
    }
  },
  voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  deleted: false,
  name: "attrib's server",
  icon: null,
  splash: null,
  discoverySplash: null,
  region: 'europe',
  memberCount: 3,
  large: false,
  features: [],
  applicationID: null,
  afkTimeout: 300,
  afkChannelID: null,
  systemChannelID: '71558641555944xxxx',
  embedEnabled: false,
  premiumTier: 0,
  premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
  verificationLevel: 'NONE',
  explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
  mfaLevel: 0,
  joinedTimestamp: 1600721822100,
  defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
  systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  maximumMembers: 250000,
  vanityURLCode: null,
  vanityURLUses: null,
  description: null,
  banner: null,
  id: '71558641511471xxxx',
  available: true,
  etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the `id` property from the `guild` object.

```js
guild.fetch().then((guild) => console.log(guild.id)).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I was pretty close. I've made the mistake by using: guild.fetch().then(guild => console.log(id).catch(console.error); - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("ready", () => {
        client.guilds.cache.forEach((val,id) => {
        console.log(id)
        })  
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.